# Find solution of PDE $x \frac {\partial z} {\partial x} +y \frac {\partial z} {\partial y}=3z$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to use Lagrange's method to solve this simple PDE but I'm stuck without being able to go beyond this point. Not sure if I'm making some mistake, but I couldn't find a way to express it in terms of *z*:

\begin{align}
  & \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y} \\ 
 & \frac{dy}{y}=3z \\ 
\end{align}
then:
\begin{align}
  & 3\frac{dx}{x}=3\frac{dy}{y} \\ 
 & 3\frac{dy}{y}=z \\ 
\end{align}
integrating:
\begin{align} 3\int{\frac{1}{x}dx-}3\int{\frac{1}{y}dy={{C}_{1}}}\end{align}
\begin{align}\frac{{{x}^{3}}}{{{y}^{3}}}={{e}^{{{C}_{1}}}}\end{align}
\begin{align}3\int{\frac{1}{y}dy-}\int{\frac{1}{z}dz={{C}_{2}}}\end{align}
\begin{align}\frac{{{y}^{3}}}{z}={{e}^{{{C}_{2}}}}\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct system of equations is
$$
\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{3z}. \tag{1}
$$
Now
$$
\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y} \Rightarrow \frac{y}{x}=C_1 \tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{dz}{3z}=\frac{dy}{y} \Rightarrow \frac{z}{y^3}=C_2. \tag{3}
$$
Therefore, the general solution to $(1)$ is
$$
f\left(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{y^3}\right)=0,\quad {\rm or}\quad z=y^3g\left(\frac{y}{x}\right), \tag{4}
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary differentiable functions.

Comment: General solution is
$$z(x,y)\rightarrow c_{1}\cdot x^{3}\cdot \mathit{f1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+c_{2}\cdot y^{3}\cdot f_{2}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

Comment: I didn't understand how you got the 
\begin{align}\frac{y}{x}=C_1\end{align}
while I 
\begin{align}\frac{{{x}^{3}}}{{{y}^{3}}}={{e}^{{{C}_{1}}}}\end{align}
Even if I didn't touch the 3z, I'd only get
\begin{align}\frac{{{x}}}{{{y}}}={{e}^{{{C}_{1}}}}\end{align}